# List of key value pairs within redis

Tags: c#, redis

Is it possible to have list of key/value pairs within redis? or possibly a set of key value pairs.

What i want to have is List of date time stamps which have counters as follows:

```
1.1.12 -> 12
1.2.12 -> 1
1.3.12 -> 3
```

I want to be able to use get the range as follows:

get range 1.1.12 to 1.2.12 and i want the result as 13.

Is this possible?

Which structures should i use?

what s the proper way of doing this?

Lets say i want to have time stamps as a set and each timestamp will point to 3-4 key value pairs as follows:

```
1.1.12 -> error : 1
          pass : 100
1.2.12 -> error : 3
          pass : 50
1.3.12 -> error : 12
          pass : 100
```

does c#  client support this?

My main goal is to be able to store this multivalue structure and be able to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to convert the date/time strings into something like "seconds since the epoch" (but perhaps using a 64 bit value if you need a larger range than 1970 through 2038 --- and perhaps using a different starting point, again, according to your application requirements).

From there I'd use a zset (a "sorted" or "scored" set which supports fetching subsets using ZRANGE and ZRANGEBY Redis operations/commands).  The seconds-since-your-epoch can be the score and your value can be any sort of encoded value you like (including a JSON or BSON encoded dictionary/hash table).  Or it could be a simple string which you use as a Redis key (thus implementing one layer of indirection --- the zset acting as an index of Redis keys).  If you choose this latter approach I'd recommend that you use a Redis stored integer to provide the unique sequence IDs for your keys --- so that will have ACID properties in the possible face of concurrent processes/nodes creating these indirect key/value pairs).

Comment: ok that s fine, not a problem but i want to be able to use counter as well. i was looking at zrange but does sortedset supports increment operation?

Comment: In general Redis doesn't support its various operations/commands on values contained within its sets, zsets, or hashes.  In other words you cannot use INCR on some score or item within a zset (you'd have to perform one operation to remove the item from the zset and another to add the only created score/value pair back into it).  There is an HINCRBY operation, but for anything other than that you might need to use HSETNX on a "lock" field ... perform your operation ... then HDEL your lock.  The value in such a lock can, perhaps, facilitate stale lock detection.

Comment: that s too much to do no? i was curious if there is an easier way to do it. perhaps a built in functionality.

Comment: You could look at the newer (beta? developmental?) versions of Redis with the experimental embedded Lua scripting support.  Then you could add something almost like your own "built-in functionality."  Alternatively you could fork the Redis code and create your own custom version of the servers.  However, if you consider doing some simple locking on your hashes using HSETNX, and HDEL to be "too much to do" then I have to wonder how I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: i rather not try to get into redis source, i can build something for this purpose, list of multivalue dictionary, i was just thinking if it s been done already. thanks.

Comment: DarthVader have you tried reading the Redis Docs? I see that there is also a ZINCRBY for incrementing the score of a ZSET item by some amount (possibly a negative number).  So you can atomically adjust the priority (sorting key) for any item in a ZSET.  Look at: http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set for details.